# Camera to behave as the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

One of the things I haven't learned about using Blender is how look from a camera and use the exact same commands to pan, rotate and zoom with the camera as I do with the viewport. I'm used to doing this with either C4D, Maya, Modo, Max, etc... but in Blender It feels like a different workflow for those who are coming from other 3D applications. Is there anything that can be done about this either in the settings or through an addon?

Comment: You can position the camera at the current place you're look at in the viewport by pressing CTRL + ALT + Numpad 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable ["Lock camera to view"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/properties/sidebar.html#dview-lock-camera-to-view). Then all navigation in the viewport will be done through the camera using the same commands as navigating on any other view in the viewport.

In 2.8+, you can access the checkbox in the right side panel in the 3D viewport with <kbd>N</kbd> :

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: That solves it. Thank you very much! I watched many tutorials and not a single one ever mentioned this. Just for others to know how to find it in 2.80, it's at the sidebar (N)>View Tab>under View Lock

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if theres a way to do that, but here's what I usually do.

*Open a new 3D view panel so you'd have **two windows with the 3d view**.

*In one panel, press 0 to go look trought the camera

*Now in the other panel you can move, rotate or whatever the camera and you'll see the results in the other window.

It's probably not as confortable as moving it directly but it's an option!