# Camera moves as I scroll in view

Tags: camera

In one viewport, I have a camera. However, the camera "rectangle" is displayed with a dashed red line which I see for the first time.

In the past, whenever I was looking at the camera view, scrolling zoomed the view - brought the camera view closer, without actually moving the camera. This is what I want. However, in this file, I must have accidentally turned something on because whenever I scroll to zoom, the camera actually moves forward, it changes its position. This also applies to newly created cameras.

How can I disable this?

Comment: You must have enabled "Lock camera to view". You can find the toggle in the right side panel (shortcut "N") > View > View > View Lock

Comment: Oh yeah, that's it :) Many thanks. Please add this as the answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has already been asked and I remember answering exactly this question something like 10 days ago :) https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179014/86891 Found the original question ! https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/144428/86891

Comment: Yes, it does answer it.